# @import illegal interface qualifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

New to iOS development. The problem I'm getting is that `@import Foundation;` is running the error:

```
illegal interface qualifier
```

Code in WXClient.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import CoreLocation;
#import <ReactiveCocoa.h>

@interface WXClient : NSObject

@import Foundation;
  - (RACSignal *)fetchJSONFromURL:(NSURL *)url;
  - (RACSignal *)fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
  - (RACSignal *)fetchHourlyForecastForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
  - (RACSignal *)fetchDailyForecastForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put your `@import` inside your class declaration. Put it with the rest of your imports. Additionally, if you're going to import Foundation as a module, there's no need to have this import `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` at all.

```
@import Foundation;
@import CoreLocation;
#import <ReactiveCocoa.h>

@interface WXClient : NSObject

  - (RACSignal *)fetchJSONFromURL:(NSURL *)url;
  - (RACSignal *)fetchCurrentConditionsForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
  - (RACSignal *)fetchHourlyForecastForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
  - (RACSignal *)fetchDailyForecastForLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I added #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> instead of @import Foundation; it seems to work.

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney You should prefer to use Objective-C Modules when you can. You can read about why here: [http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html).